# Can sonarqube gitlab plugin only scan changed files

Tags: maven, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

I'm using gitlab-ci pipeline, it will run a new docker container with following commands:

```
mvn --batch-mode verify sonar:sonar 
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview 
-Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_ID 
-Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA 
-Dsonar.gitlab.only_issue_from_commit_file=true 
-Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME 
-Dsonar.host.url=xxx 
-Dsonar.test.inclusions="/src/test/java/**/*.java" 
-Dsonar.login=xxx
```

It becomes quite slow for my project, almost run for 20mins.
I found it will scan all files instead of only the commited files.

Is there anything wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 1):

In some past SonarQube versions we changed the preview mode to only scan changed files. But it has some drawback, like not being able to properly detect cross file issues.

In recent SonarQube versions, the preview mode is deprecated in favor of pull request analysis. But even this PR analysis feature is scanning all files, for the same reasons (cross file issues, coverage measures, duplication detections, ...).

We stopped trying to do partial analysis, and are instead trying to optimize full analysis duration. How big is your project? Is SonarQube analysis time long compared to your regular build (compile + tests)? If yes, then I suggest you report you case on the [SonarSource community forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/).